# Are these rectangles created as a "struct of arrays" or as an "array of structs"?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Apple is talking about [avoiding creating a "struct of arrays" and preferring "array of structs"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) for much better memory performance.

In the example below, we create a huge grid of colored rectangles (32 x 48 rects, each 10 x 10 big). Is this generating a "struct of arrays"? Just wanna know how bad my weekend will be...

```
- (void)drawFrame {
    // draw grid
    for (int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {
        // ... calculate CGPoint values for vertices ...

        GLshort vertices[ ] = {
            bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y,
            bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y,
            topLeft.x, topLeft.y,
            topRight.x, topRight.y
        };

        glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, vertices);           
        glColor4f(r, g, b, 1);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a loop, making an array of coordinates for one rectangle. You're not involving structs. They're specifically talking about interpolating vertex, color, and texture coordinates. As you're just setting the color and passing only vertices, there's no interpolation to do.

If your grid coordinates are constant, you can see a performance increase by filling a large array with all the vertices just once during init.

You can then increment the `first` argument to [glDrawArrays](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glDrawArrays.xml) to step through the array and draw the individual rects, simplifying the memory operations in your render loop (because you already have the vertices in an array for every render call).

```
// assuming you know the numbers beforehand
// also you should probably put this in a property
GLshort gridVerts[numRectangles][8];

- (void)init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {
        // calculate the vertices

        GLshort vertices[] = {
            bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y,
            bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y,
            topLeft.x, topLeft.y,
            topRight.x, topRight.y
        };

        memcpy(&gridVerts[i][0], vertices, sizeof(GLshort) * 8));
    }
}

- (void)drawFrame() {
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, gridVerts);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {
        // calculate the color for this iteration
        glColor4f(r, g, b, 1);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, i * 4, 4);
    }
}
```

To answer the original question about arrays of structs, [Vertex Buffers in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578091/vertex-buffers-in-opengl) has an example.

Comment: Are you suggesting a Vertex Buffer Object in this case? What's the difference between using a VBO and the method you described? The color is changed in every loop iteration (just stripped that part out to simplify it).

Comment: If your loop is always ending up with the same vertices and colors, it's very wasteful to regenerate them every frame. In this case - you need to pack both colors and vertices. Apple's "array of structs" advice will be useful and I can show you how to do that :) Even if you're using a VBO, you need to pack the data all into one array first.

Comment: Thanks! I'm always using the same geometry (a grid of rectangles, basically) but not the same colors. Colors change in every iteration. I guess "array of structs" will not be useful then, right? I mean actually I just want to modify the colors per rectangle afterwards in every iteration, but not the geometry. A simple example with two rectangles would be great! Having a hard time finding something as simplified as this :-)

Comment: In this case, you might actually want to keep two separate arrays like Apple advises against - just so you can save yourself the trouble of regenerating the vertex struct. You can do it either way, depends on whether your CPU or GPU is hurting more during the render loop (one way requires extra memory operations on the CPU end, the other probably makes for more cache hits during rendering on the GPU).

Comment: Edited my answer to something like what I meant, that precomputes vertices and reuses the array every frame. This (ugly C) is not necessarily the best way to allocate and fill an array for your purposes (for example, you can use C++ STL arrays to store vertices). You can put this array in a VBO, but that's another topic.

Comment: So using a VBO would be more efficient after all, if I would be only modifying color values in subsequent frames but not the geometry?

Comment: A VBO just takes what I did above and makes it only transfer to the graphics processor once. Baby steps :)

Comment: Looks good! When I call memcpy in a loop, will it add the rectangle to the VBO? Or must I call memcpy in one big shot to create the VBO all at once? And can I use GL_TRIANGLES instead to be able to set a solid color per triangle rather than interpolating colors between triangles? (I think that's what would happen if using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and setting vertex colors)

Comment: Sorry I got confused with VBOs now. That's not a VBO here. How would I set per-triangle color when I had used a VBO instead?

Comment: You can still do multiple glDrawArrays calls exactly as you do here when using a VBO, it just saves on GPU bandwidth to use a VBO. Here's a VBO example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906742/drawing-interleaved-vbo-with-gldrawarrays